# indefinite nature of the grail (Indiana Jones)?

Tags: story-identification, indiana-jones, holy-grail

Acording to the Indiana-Jones-wiki...

> Years later [i.e.: after "The last Crusade"], the elder Jones remarked
> on the elusive, indefinite nature of the Grail, commenting that the
> cup discovered by the father-son team was simply "a Grail. But many of
> the oldest Grail texts, written by the most ancient seers, refer to
> the Grail as an elixir, as a bread, a powder, gold, or a stone."

Could anyone please tell me, where (i.e. in which novel) this quote can be found?
I would be really grateful for help, because I couldn't find the answer via google and my local library hasn't got the Indiana Jones-novels.

### Edit:

The Indiana-Jones-wiki lists the following novels or films, in which the grail appears or is mentioned:

> Young Indiana Jones and the Ghostly Riders (Mentioned only)
> The Mata Hari Affair (Mentioned only)
> The Day of Destiny (Mentioned only)
> The Secret Treaty (Mentioned only)
> The Rule of Russia (Mentioned only)
> Indiana Jones and the Emperor's Tomb (Mentioned only)
> Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (First appearance)
> Indiana Jones and the Mystery of Mount Sinai (Mentioned only)
> Indiana Jones and the Spear of Destiny

I first thought this might indicate, that the quote should be taken from the "Mystery of Mount Sinai" or the "Spear of Destiny", because they both take place after the incidents of "The Last Crusade". On the other hand, the sources of the wiki-article only list the following items:

> Grail Diary
> Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom Sourcebook
> Close Encounters of the Random Kind (Ambiguously canonical source)
> Indiana Jones: The Ultimate Guide
> Indiana Jones: The Official Magazine 3
> The Greatest Adventures of Indiana Jones

Comment: Could be the [novel](http://indianajones.wikia.com/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Last_Crusade_(novel)), the [video games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Last_Crusade_(video_game)) or the [junior novel](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2305908.Indiana_Jones_and_the_Last_Crusade) ? Get hunting Stackeologists!

Comment: Isn't the only time we see the older Jones in the Young Indiana Jones chronicles? As there's a lot of those episodes that's going to be quite a bit of hunting to be done

Comment: Would the 'elder' Jones be Jones Senior (Indiana's father) or simply an older Indiana?  May help to at least eliminate some searching, hopefully.

Comment: If you read my answer it is clear that elder Jones is Henry Jones, Sr.  He is identified as Henry, and talks to "Junior" who referrs to him "Dad".

Answer (score 5):

The quote is from [Mystery of Mount Sinai](http://www.amazon.ca/Indiana-Jones-Monsters-Mount-Sinai/dp/0545112060/ref=pd_sim_b_24#reader_0545112060) on page 37. I typed the quote below, but if you search "grail" in the book preview you can read the whole page.

> "Junior, the Grail legend is as old as time," Henry insisted, looking up. "The Grail was a cup, but it was also many other things - a blood line and a holy elixir."
>
> "But Dad, we found *the* Grail."
>
> "Correction, Junior. We found a cup that was *a* Grail," Henry explained. "But many of the oldest Grail texts, written by the most ancient seers, refer to the Grail as an elixir, as a bread, a powder, gold, or a stone." He closed the book with a snap and suddenly said. "I've got it!"